# Access value in getter inside defineProperty

Tags: javascript, getter-setter, defineproperty

can i access the value that i have defined inside a defineProperty call? I want create something like this:

```
Object.defineProperty(this, 'name', {
  value: 'Caaaarl',
  get: function() { return <the value>; },
  set: function(x) { <the value> = x; }
});
```

Currently I have to create a second attribute for each property.

```
var _name = '';

Object.defineProperty(this, 'name', {
  get: function() { return _name; },
  set: function(x) { _name = x; }
});
```

Thanks for every help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not legal to have both a `value` and either `get` or `set` fields in the property descriptor.

If you wish to make a more complicated property with getters and setters that do more than merely set the property without polluting the namespace, you may hold the underlying value in a closure:

```
(function() {
    var value = 'Caaarl';

    Object.defineProperty(this, 'name', {
        get: function() {
             // do some stuff
             ...
             return value;
        },
        set: function(v) {
             // do some stuff
             ...
             value = v;
        },
        enumerable: true
    });
}).call(this);
```

Comment: you can't have the property `writable` with `get` or `set` -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty `If a descriptor has both value or writable and get or set keys, an exception is thrown.`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're just trying to make a straightforward property, you just want it to be writable:

```
Object.defineProperty(this, 'name', {
  value: 'Caaaarl',
  writable: true
});
```

Then you can do this to change the value:

```
this.name = 'Carl';
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to rewrite the setter and getter if you are not customizing them.

This create the "name" property and sets as default Caarl

```
Object.defineProperty(this, 'name', {
   value: 'Caaarl'
});
```

If you need to customize the setter and getter, the variable scoping(as you are doing) is the [official way](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Adding_properties_and_default_values).

By the way, you can also refer to the object with this:

```
var a = {};
Object.defineProperty(a, 'random', {
  get: function() { return 'Getter -> ' + this._random; },
  set: function(x) { this._random = 'Setter -> ' + x; }
});
```

So a default could be as simple as:

```
var a = {_random: 'default'};
console.log(a.random); //undefined
Object.defineProperty(a, 'random', {
  get: function() { return 'Getter -> ' + this._random; },
  set: function(x) { this._random = 'Setter -> ' + x; }
});
console.log(a.random);//undefined but getting custom getter
a.random = 'daniel';
console.log(a.random);//sweet
```